# Javascript is not being implemented

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to build a background animation for the menu items of my website. It mostly works as I want but I'm not able to get the javascript to work. The folders are all in the same directory and the code is as follows:

```js
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item"))
  .forEach((item, index) => {
    item.onmouseover = () => {
      menu.dataset.activeIndex = index;
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  margin: 0px;
}

#menu {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-item {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: clamp(3rem, 8vw, 8rem);
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: clamp(0.25rem, 0.5vw, 1rem) 0rem;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

#menu-items {
  margin-left: clamp(4rem, 20vw, 48rem);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#menu-items:hover>.menu-item {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

#menu-items:hover>.menu-item:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu-background-pattern {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: radial-gradient( rgba(2255, 255, 255, 0.1) 9%, transparent 9%);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 12vmin 12vmin;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 800ms ease, background-size 800ms ease;
}

#menu-items:hover~#menu-background-pattern {
  background-size: 11vmin 11vmin;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#menu[data-active-index="0"]>#menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -25%;
}

#menu[data-active-index="1"]>#menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -50%;
}

#menu[data-active-index="2"]>#menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -75%;
}

#menu[data-active-index="3"]>#menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="menu-items">
    <a href="/" class="menu-item">Home</a>
    <a href="/" class="menu-item">Shop</a>
    <a href="/" class="menu-item">About</a>
    <a href="/" class="menu-item">Contact US</a>
  </div>
  <div id="menu-background-pattern"></div>
</div>
```

I want the background to update with an animation as I hover over menu items. Where exactly did I go wrong?

Comment: Has the document finished loading when `document.getElementById("menu")` is called? Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and make sure the DOM is loaded before you execute any javascript that uses the DOM:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item"))
    .forEach((item, index) => {
      item.onmouseover = () => {
        menu.dataset.activeIndex = index;
      }
    });
});
```